# How to derive $\ A^∗(u_1 × u_2)=(Au_1) × (Au_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to derive from

$\ A^∗[u]_× = [Au]_×A $

to

$\ A^∗(u_1 × u_2)=(Au_1) × (Au_2)$

**A** is 3 x 3 matrix, $\ A^*$ is matrix of cofactors of **A**, **u** is 3 x 1 column vector, $\ [u]_×$ is the matrix form of cross product with **u**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $\ A^∗[u]_× = [Au]_×A$ true for any **u**

then
$\ A^∗[u_1]_× = [Au_1]_×A$

multiply both side by $\ \mathbf u_2:$
$\ A^∗[u_1]_× u_2= [Au_1]_×Au_2$

because of associativity of matirx multiplication: $\ A^∗([u_1]_× u_2)= [Au_1]_×(Au_2)$

convert matirx multiplication to cross multiplication:$\ A^∗(u_1 × u_2)= (Au_1)×(Au_2)$

Done